# postfix virtual_alias_maps map lookup failed [fixed]

Tags: arch-linux, postgresql, postfix

Running postfix on archlinux with virtual user configuration, I get the following error message:

> postfix/cleanup[17859]: warning: 1C0F715008: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for < recipient > -- message not accepted, try again later

The alias table is empty (no alias). There is no problem with database server connection.

I follow the archlinux [Virtual user mail system with Postfix, Dovecot and Roundcube](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Virtual_user_mail_system_with_Postfix,_Dovecot_and_Roundcube#Setting_up_Postfix) tutorial.

What could be wrong? How to change Postfix log level to have more details?

Comment: what is the full text of the warning?

Comment: I update the message with the last part.

Comment: check syntax of your sql queries, etc.  and check spelling of filename/path to sql lookups in `postconf -n`

Comment: Server host is "mail.domain.dom". "domain.dom" is added to domain table
"user@domain.dom" is added to mailbox table. Test send mail to "user@domain.dom". Is there something wrong in the logic ?

Comment: Enabling log on postgres server show an error un the SQL request. There were a remaining mistake in the virtual_alias_map.cf.

Answer (score 1):

Same error message here after upgrade to Postfix 3.3.0.

I solved this by added tls keys in the virtual maps. Note that it must be `tls_cert_file` and not `smtpd_tls_cert_file` as in main.cf
source: http://www.postfix.org/mysql_table.5.html

example: `/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf`

```
user = mail
password = <pwd>
hosts = localhost
dbname = mail
tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/cert.pem
tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/privkey.pem
tls_CAfile=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/chain.pem
query = SELECT CONCAT(domain, '/', local_part, '/') FROM mailbox WHERE username='%s' AND active = '1'
```

Comment: Are you saying this fixes the problem that was asked, or just that you're having the same problem?

Comment: I just got the same error message in a system that used to work before. In my case the problem was the TLS parameters in the alias maps. I don't see these parameters in the tutorial you followed. I hope this can help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an issue with the PostgreSQL server, so when postfix was trying to connect with config settings that previously worked, it was spewing that error. I had to restart PostgreSQL, and then the log errors stopped.